# Javascript Password Generator how to ensure password meets criteria

Tags: javascript, passwords, generator

for a project I needed to make a password generator that out puts a password between 8-128 characters containing: numbers, symbols, uppercase, and lowercase letters. I successfully made it, it works and looks nice.

I was wondering, how would I be able to ensure that the password that has been created contains at least one aspect of each element? Like an uppercase letter, lowercase, number, and symbol.